# How to use Enterprise Security Application block?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Looking to implement authentication/authorisation for ASP.NET app

Was looking into using Provider model MembershipProvider SQLServerMembershipProvider etc as makes good sense to me.

However I'm looking into the Enterprise Security Application block as well. My question is can/should the two be used in tandem?

Comment: Only one question mark is needed in your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise Security Application block provides you the facility to choose your Authorization Rule Provider and it can be configured to use the MembershipProvider. So yo your question, You can very well use ESAB in your application if you looking for layer agnostic authorization. Still you will need to use your preferred Authentication mechanism in ASP.NET (Forms/Windows)..

In other words: if you have sufficient time you can use ESAB. For a rapid development scene, go ahead with MembershipProvider and customize it to suit your needs. ESAB is more appropriate for enterprise level applications where you not only need authentication/authorisation  but also caching.